# Error en configuración de Beans

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

Buenas tengo el siguiente código  en el application-context de mi proyecto.

```
bean id="bean" class="ej.tutorial.spring.model.MyBean" />
<bean id="beanSvc" class="ej.tutorial.spring.model.OtherBean">
<property name="mBean" ref="bean"/>
</bean>
```

Las clases son la siguientes:

```
public class MyBean {

private int valor;
private String msg;

public MyBean(){

}

public MyBean(int valor,String msg){
    this.valor = valor;
    this.msg = msg;
}

public int getValor() {
    return valor;
}

public void setValor(int valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
   }
}
```

clase OtherBean:

```
public class OtherBean {

private MyBean mBean;

public OtherBean(){

}

public OtherBean(MyBean bean){
    this.mBean = bean;
}

public MyBean getmBean() {
    return mBean;
}

public void setmBean(MyBean mBean) {
    this.mBean = mBean;
    }

}
```

Pues me da un error el aplication-context.El error es el siguiente.

> No setter found for property 'mBean' in class 'ej.tutorial.spring.model.OtherBean

La verdad que no le encuentro explicación lógica ya que el setter del atributo mBean esta definido en la clase OtherBean.

Comment: te falta definir la propiedad de `mBean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para propiedades, los getters y setters se nombran como:

- `get/is/set`<sup>1</sup> , seguido de
- nombre de la propiedad, **con la primera letra en mayúscula**.

Así, para la propiedad `mBean`, deberías definir los métodos `getMBean()` y `setMBean(MBean mBean)`.

---

<sup>1</sup>En teoría, si la propiedad es de tipo `boolean`, el getter debería empezar por `is` en vez de `get`, pero no conozco ningún framework que no encuentre el getter si lo escribes con `get`.

Cuidado que si la propiedad es `Boolean`, entonces sí que debe usarse `get`.

Comment: Muchas Gracias,Era eso y no lo veía .

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya ido bien, aunque deberías marcar la respuesta como correcta para hacerlo más evidente (una marca al lado de los puntos).

Answer (score 0):

En tu `applicationContex.xml` define tu bean y su propiedad :

```
<bean id="myBean" class="ej.tutorial.spring.model.OtherBean">
        <property name="mBean" >
            <ref local="mBean"/>
       </property>
</bean>

  <bean id="mBean" class="ej.tutorial.spring.model.MyBean">
  </bean>
```